# How to search for entries in the previous day, starting from 8:00 AM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 2.3.6 I'd like to search the database for entries between today 8:00 AM and previous day at 8:00 AM.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Augusto

Answer (score 1):

Under Rails 3, example below retrieves users created in range you need:

```
today8am = Time.now.at_beginning_of_day + 8.hours
@users = User.where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", today8am - 1.day, today8am)
```

If there may be many records and query is called very often I suggest to [add index](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index) on date column.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. If answer satisfies you and works for you, you can reward the author by accepting the answer.